# Supporting Non-ASCII Characters in Boto3 put_object Tagging

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, non-ascii-characters

We are using *boto3* to upload files to *AWS S3*. We need to add Tags to the files and have successfully added tags to each file when we upload them.

The problem is that *boto3* throws an exception for invalid Value when the strings contain Non-ASCII characters like:

> ñ Ñ ó ú Ö

But S3 supports Non-ASCII characters in their Tagging as I've successfully set them manually.
How can we enable support for UTF-8 chars on Boto3's *put_object* method's Tagging?

Here's our code:

```
form = await request.form()
contents = await form["upload_file"].read()
s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=C.ACCESS_KEY_S3, aws_secret_access_key=C.SECRET_KEY_S3)
response = s3.put_object(
            Body=contents,
            Bucket=C.S3_BUCKET,
            Key='{id}/{filename}'.format(id=deviceID, filename=filename),
            ACL='public-read' if public else "private",
            Tagging=tagging if tagging is not None else "" #typical: "title=Título&comments=Ññ"
            )
```

And here's the exception:

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 635, in _make_api_call
raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidTag) when calling the PutObject operation: The TagValue you have provided is invalid
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [S3 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html):

```
Amazon S3 allows arbitrary Unicode characters in your metadata values.

To avoid issues around the presentation of these metadata values, you should conform to using US-ASCII characters when using REST and UTF-8 when using SOAP or browser-based uploads via POST.
```

Non-ASCII characters are only allowed on browser based uploads and SOAP.

According to [official boto3 git page](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/478), you may use boto to upload Non-ASCII metadata, but it is not guaranteed (due to updates) as boto uses REST and only US-ASCII are allowed in REST.